# Google fit permission check returns true even when disconnected

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

So I use the following to check if google fit has established a connectiong

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    }
```

I'm running android 11 (so above Q). I've gone into the google fit app, and disconected the app, but this is still returning true.

Comment: What do you mean by "disconnected the app"? You can isolate which step is failing by checking out the logs on the device or using a test device to reproduce. I tried replicating but I realize that might be difficult to arrange, but will be a critical step in getting to an actionable result.

Comment: I go into the google fit app -> settings -> connected apps -> disconnect all